# Historical Precursor to な?

Tags: history, particle-な

Prior to the development of the な particle (presumably from なる) several hundred years ago, what constructions were used where な-construtions are currently used? E.g. in the phase きれいな女, would that have been きれいの女, 女のきれい, きれい女 (and would that be kireionna or kirei onna?), きれいなる女　or something else?

Comment: I think that なる is used.

Comment: なる is still sometimes seen, e.g. 父なる神様 = Father God in Christianity.

Comment: http://www.genji.co.jp/yougen/narikatu.htm#narikatu 「源氏物語に出てくる『用言』を、活用の種類別・多い順(※)に表にしました。」, eg 静かなり. Note that たる adjectives were in use as well, eg 堂々たる.

Comment: I suppose it would be 堂々たり predicatively? Is たる a 四段 or ラ変 suffix?

Comment: なり and たり conjugate like ラ変 verbs.

Comment: 「きれいな女」の「な」って、助詞なの？

Comment: @Chocolate 助詞というより助動詞かな？

Comment: Sorry, are you asking what developed into なる, or what developed into な?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is from なる, in a way; but it may not be the one you're thinking of. The なる here is the 連体形 of the former copula なり, which itself derives from に+あり (modern ある). This seems to have been the copula as far back as we have records of. Indeed, this kind of adjective is younger than the copula it uses - these kinds of adjectives do not occur before the Heian-jidai.

A couple of forms do appear that have since become them (e.g. adjectives ending in -らか), but I don't know how these were used - my source (Bentley's Descriptive Grammar of Old Japanese Prose) mentions their existence, but only says that these なり-based adjectives are new as of the Heian-jidai; it says nothing at all about how they were used in Old Japanese. I would speculate that they're used in the very old adjective patterns that require no morphology at all: so just like you can get /awo sora/ (/səra/?) where you would expect /awo-ki sora/, I bet you could get /tapiraka umi/ when later you would expect /taɸiraka=naru umi/ (for 平らかな海).

As for きれい, it's a Chinese loanword, and was loaned after the creation of these kinds of adjectives. So there was never a point in time before きれいなる女 - you would have used a native Japanese word like 美しい, and so you would have either /utukusi-ki womina/ or the older /utukusi womina/.

Comment: /utukusi/ would be the 終止形【しゅうしけい】 or terminal form, which only ended a sentence.  As such, /utukusi womina/ would not be correct.  The 連体形【れんたいけい】 or attributive form would have to be used for the adjective to directly precede a noun, which would have been /utukusiki/.  This is already the case in the *Man'yōshū*, written starting some time between the 300s or 400s and finalized around the mid-700s.

Comment: Also, /awo/ and the other root Japanese color words (/aka/, /shiro/, /kuro/) are also nouns, so /awo sora/ is a compound of two nouns.  /awoki/ as an adjective is indeed used, but not so much in set phrases, where the compound is the shorter and simpler formation.

Comment: Lastly, the -らか and -やか adjectives were formed by adding suffixes -ら and -や, with -か then later added on as another suffix.  According to Shogakukan, both -ら and -や indicated "XX kind of state or circumstances".  -ら may be related to pluralizing suffix -ら as in 我【われ】ら, which was also used to imply "[noun] kind of thing", and -や may be related to particle や, similarly used to imply "[noun] kind of thing".  Final suffix -か also indicated "kind of state", and I've read theories that this is related to the -か, -こ, and -く suffixes indicating "place, area".

Comment: All that said, though, 平【たひ】ら is a compound of prefix た- (of indeterminate meaning, apparent emphasizer) and ひら "flat".  たひらか is thus たひら + か, not たひ + らか.  There was also a regular /-si/ adjectival form たひらけし, with adjectivizing suffix -けし apparently 気 + し, a bit like modern 気【げ】 + な.

Answer (score 4):

As others have noted, the modern な particle used with *-na* adjectives evolved from なる, itself *not* the verb なる "to become", but instead a contraction of にある "to be in a state".  So from newest form to oldest, using your example of きれい, we would have:

- 綺麗な女
- 綺麗なる女
- 綺麗にある女

The *-naru* form is still used in modern poetry and other contexts to give things a somewhat archaic and formal sense, such as in 静{しず}かなる田舎{いなか}, *the quiet contryside*.

Although the classical *-naru* adjectives did indeed seem to develop mostly in the [Heian period](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heian_period) (794-1185), the construction of [noun phrase] + にある + [noun] can already be found in the *Man'yōshū*, dating to some time between the mid-300s and the mid-700s.  Example:

- [Poem 165](http://etext.lib.virginia.edu/japanese/manyoshu/Man2Yos.html#165):
  宇都曽見乃 人尓有吾哉 従
  うつそみの人{ひと}にある我{わ}れや
  Here, *utsusomi no hito* is a noun phrase ("person in the real world", i.e. "someone who is still alive") used to modify *ware* ("I, me").

There is also at least one example I found of what may be an early *-ni aru* adjective in the *Man'yōshū*, 寛{ゆた}, classed in Shogakukan's *Kokugo Dai Jiten* as a 形容動詞{けいようどうし} (*-na* adjective):

- [Poem 2367](http://etext.lib.virginia.edu/japanese/manyoshu/Man11Yo.html#2367):
  大舟之 由多尓将有 人兒由恵尓
  大船{おほぶね}のゆたにあるらむ人{ひと}の子{こ}ゆゑに
  *...because [you're] the child of a person who is steadfast like a big ship*
  Here, the phrase *ohobune no yuta* ("big ship's easygoing-ness / steadfastness / steadiness") is used to modify *hito*.

If you're interested in the history of *-na* adjectives, the [概要 section of the JA Wikipedia article on 形容動詞](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E5%BD%A2%E5%AE%B9%E5%8B%95%E8%A9%9E#.E6.A6.82.E8.A6.81) describes how Heian-period writers suffixed -にあり (becoming -なり) and -とあり (becoming -たり) to nouns to create new classes of adjectives.